# Shower head with easy on/off switch

Tags: bathroom, shower, bathroom-fixtures

I am making a new bathroom with tub where I want the shower to have easy on/off system. I can't find such thing at homedepot or lowes.

Typically you have to dial the mixer starting from to warm and this is how you turn on/off as well.

But I want the mixer to be one settings and ability to shut off shower and turn it on back at the same level (very much like single lever faucet).

Is there anything like that available on market? Do I have to improvise otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is available. Unfortunately the only way you can maintain the same temperature setting without hot water delay's is to also install a hot water recirculation pump.

Mixing Valve see this link... 
http://www.deltafaucet.com/smart-solutions/tempassure.html

Hot water recirculation pump see this link.... 
http://www.supplyhouse.com/Grundfos-595916-UP15-10SU7P-TLC-Comfort-Hot-Water-Recirculation-Pump-3-4-NPT-115-V?gclid=CODm_PqOlswCFcJahgodTNAF8g

Answer (score 2):

There are certainly shower heads with their own flow control valves, and I know such valves used to be available separately to be installed between wall and head.

There are also mixing valves which separate temperature and flow, though most of the ones sold in the US seem to put on/off on the temp control, perhaps for some obscure liability reason.

So yes, it probably exists... But it may be hard to find or require importing.

Answer (score 1):

This will probably be closed as a shopping question, but a search for "shower head on off valve" gives you many results for valves that go in-line between the shower head and feed pipe, such as [this from Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HSWPYIG).

Comment: Thanks and yes something like that but it is not the perfect. I just can't find the right assembly for it. I would just like to have a proper sizable lever which I can pull up or down to stop/start flow. I just can't find it.

Comment: I think I found the right thing, its [here](http://www.amazon.com/Faucet-T17064-Ashlyn-Monitor-Series/dp/B00OTY7ODY/ref=pd_sim_sbs_60_3?ie=UTF8&dpID=51HlQYiAzZL&dpSrc=sims&preST=_AC_UL160_SR160%2C160_&refRID=182RCWCZ58XQKTSADBDJ)

Comment: @zar That looks like what Been There linked to. Was that type your solution?

Comment: That was useful but since I am making a new bathroom, I settled for [this](http://www.amazon.com/KTSDVE-T17453-SS-Pressure-Balance-Dual-Function-Cartridge-Brilliance/dp/B00I5QYPAM/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_2?s=hi&ie=UTF8&qid=1463577176&sr=1-2-fkmr0&keywords=Delta+Vero+Dual+Function+Pressure+Balanced+Thermostatic+Bath+and+Shower+Trim)